# Oracle query not returning expected records

Tags: sql, oracle

If I execute the query

```
select * from my_table where status=5000
```

I get 76 records from the database. However, I would like to narrow this down by date. Luckily there is a `receiveddate` column in the table and one of the records has a `receiveddate` of "23-APR-13". So I tried this query:

```
select * 
  from my_table 
 where status=5000 
   and receiveddate=to_date('23-APR-13', 'DD-Mon-YY')
```

and 0 records are returned.

If I use

```
select * 
  from my_table 
 where status=5000 
   and receiveddate > to_date('20130423', 'YYYYMMDD') 
   and receiveddate > to_date('20130424', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

I get exactly what I want. Can you guys and gals help me understand the difference/problem?

Comment: Value of `Date` data type always has time part. Try to truncate it, `trunc(receiveddate) = to_date('23-APR-13', 'DD-Mon-YY')`

Comment: I assume that the query that is returning the data you expect is actually `receiveddate < to_date('20130424', 'YYYYMMDD')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
select * 
  from my_table 
 where status=5000 
   and trunc(receiveddate)=to_date('23-APR-13', 'DD-Mon-YY')
```

trunc will return the date part of the long date which includes time also.

Comment: Just remember to be careful when using `where trunc(date_column) = mydate` . If you expect Oracle to use an index on date_column, it won't happen but instead possibly full table scan (depending on other indexes available.) In such cases you'd either need a function based index on `trunc(date_column)` or instead query with `where date_column >= mydate and date_column < mydate+1` . For this question it probably won't matter if for example there is index on status column, but in general be careful having functions on columns in predicates...